# Can "In a sense" be used as "On the one hand"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Is it okay if I start a sentence with the phrase *"In a (or one) sense"* instead of *"On one hand"* while comparing two things? If so, what about usage of *"On the other hand"* in starting the counterpoint?

Answer (score 1):

In a sense means "partly true, or true in one way". You could say "in one sense, my brother is a wicked man; in another sense he is not".

Comment: Does it mean I can use it interchangeably with "On the one hand"? Because I think "On the one hand" also means "true in one way" as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You use "in a sense" with meanings. As in:

> I say *(this)*. In a sense, it is true. In the other is not.

In this particular case, IF there are ONLY two possible senses, you can use "on one hand".

But there can be more senses to a statement. In that case, "on one hand" is not suitable, unless you are willing to get to the part with: "**On the fifth hand**...".

---

Additionally, "On one hand" can be used with anything, not only meanings of statements.

> **On one hand**, I want to enjoy the hot sun. **On the other hand**, I do not want the ice cream to melt, considering I do not have a freezer.

As you can see, "on one hand" is a lot more generic, but applicable when there are only two options to be compared.